# Using apollo/react-hooks stuck in login & can't receive token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo-client

I tried to use useMutation on this login.js, but there is somthing wrong.
first I typo password,it get error.
and then use correct password(it should redirect to home & receive token),it still stuck in login.
Even if I use Mutation component, it still got same problem.
Maybe there is something wrong on useState or other.
How can I do this code?

```
const Signin = props => {
    const [signinUser, {loading, error}] = useMutation(SIGNIN_USER)
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: ''
    })

    const  { username, password } = values

    const handleChange = name => event => {
        setValues({...values, [name]: event.target.value})
    }

    const onSubmit = (e, signinUser) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        signinUser({
            variables: { username, password }
        }).then( async ({data}) => {
            console.log(data)
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.signinUser.token)
            await props.refetch()
            setValues({
                ...values,
                username: '',
                password: ''
            })
            props.history.push('/')
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e)
        })
    }

    const validateForm = () => {
        const isValidate = 
            !username || !password
        return isValidate
    }

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <h2 className='App'>SignIn</h2>
            {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
            <form 
                className='form' 
                onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e, signinUser)}
            >
                <input 
                    type='text' 
                    name='username' 
                    placeholder='Username' 
                    value={username}
                    onChange={handleChange('username')} 
                />
                <input 
                    type='password' 
                    name='password' 
                    placeholder='Password' 
                    value={password}
                    onChange={handleChange('password')} 
                />
                <button 
                    type='submit' 
                    className='button-primary'
                    disabled={loading || validateForm() || error}
                >
                    Submit
                </button>
                {error && <Error error={error}/>}
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

There is origin worked perfectly.

```
const initialState = {
  username: "",
  password: ""
};

class Signin extends React.Component {
  state = { ...initialState };

  clearState = () => {
    this.setState({ ...initialState });
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event, signinUser) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    signinUser().then(async ({ data }) => {
      // console.log(data);
      localStorage.setItem("token", data.signinUser.token);
      await this.props.refetch();
      this.clearState();
      this.props.history.push("/");
    });
  };

  validateForm = () => {
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    const isInvalid = !username || !password;
    return isInvalid;
  };

  render() {
    const { username, password } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2 className="App">Signin</h2>
        <Mutation mutation={SIGNIN_USER} variables={{ username, password }}>
          {(signinUser, { data, loading, error }) => {
            return (
              <form
                className="form"
                onSubmit={event => this.handleSubmit(event, signinUser)}
              >
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="username"
                  placeholder="Username"
                  value={username}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={loading || this.validateForm()}
                  className="button-primary"
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
                {error && <Error error={error} />}
              </form>
            );
          }}
        </Mutation>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Mycode](https://github.com/Hankscr459/MERN_GraphQL_RecipeProject/tree/master/client/src/components/Auth)

sorry for my poor eng

Comment: At a glance, those components seem equivalent. So if the second component renders the correct route after `history.push` and the first component does not, the question is "how is the route component decided"? I'm guessing it's based on whatever query you are refetching... so is that query being refetched with the expected results?

Comment: fiexd that. this is my typo. <button 
                    type='submit' 
                    className='button-primary'
                    disabled={loading || validateForm() || error}
                >      remove ( || error)      XD